# ajax MaskedEditValidator isValidEmpty disables all webcontrols

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-controls

Or so it should, the point is : if it will **just tell you** that it's not valid to 
leave current field empty,
you could finish other fields and might *forget*  that one ..

point is cleared.

now , say I want to cancel the whole deal I will not fill this form at all !

Luckily there's a "cancel" image button

that hides the  `form`,  **but it's also disabled**.

Is there any work around other than pretend you're about to fill the form and then hit cancel as soon as the `invalidEmpty-Error` clears ?

MaskedEditExtender

```
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender enabled="true" MaskType="Date" ID="insertDate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TBXinsertDate"  InputDirection="LeftToRight"  CultureName="en-GB" 
    UserDateFormat="None" Mask="99/99/9999" MessageValidatorTip="true"  OnFocusCssClass="maskedFocus" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" ErrorTooltipCssClass="toolTipForInvalid"
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

MaskedEditValidator

```
<cc1:MaskedEditValidator Enabled="false" IsValidEmpty="false" ID="insertDate_MskValidator"  ControlExtender="insertDate_MaskedEditExtender" ControlToValidate="TBXinsertDate" runat="server"
    InvalidValueBlurredMessage="invalid date" EmptyValueBlurredText="requierd fileld"  ErrorMessage="Error" 
    MaximumValue="01/01/2015" MinimumValue="01/01/2008" MinimumValueBlurredText="please enter year above 2008" MaximumValueBlurredMessage="max year value is 2015" 
    CssClass="dateInValid">
</cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Default state of validator `Enabled = false` because I am turning it to enabled via  `onClick` of a button event from code behind .

```
  insertDate_MskValidator.Enabled = true;
```

stage 1 -

validator-enabled = false

form is hidden

stage 2 -

validator-enabled = true + Form visible

stage 3 -

cancel or submit

Submit will do if form is valid.
Cancel is no option if you step in one of text box

Is there any way you could think of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a remarkable way (so i think ! )
to get around it so 
 you can now use the Validation attribute -  `isValidEmpty=false`  ( current field is a required field )

but now you can still cancel form when field is empty even though it is not available by default

fixed the issue of :  when leaving an empty field, cause surrounding controls to be  disabled .

all i needed to do is when the event of  `onblur` is firing the validation

i am binding a function to `target textbox` `onblur()` that executes a `setTimeOut` function that execute a delay to disable the Validator as follows :

```html
   function setTDisableValidation() {
        setTimeout('disableValidation()', 3500);
    }

    function disableValidation() {
        var myVal = document.getElementById('insertDate_MskValidator');
        myVal.disabled = true;
        myVal.ValidEmpty = true;

    }

            <asp:TextBox ID="TBXinsertDate" runat="server" ToolTip="insert date" Width="76px" onblur="setTDisableValidation();">
                    </asp:TextBox>
```

i am not a javascript expert not even in asp.net (yet...) so i think this code could be refactored / optimised so it will be more elegant and will accept any control given as parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEffectiveTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EffectiveTo", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' Width="8em" ToolTip="MM/DD/YYYY"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeEffectiveTo" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbEffectiveTo" Mask="99C99C9999" MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"  OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" MaskType="None" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" Filtered="/" PromptCharacter=" " />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevEffectiveTo" runat="server" ControlExtender="meeEffectiveTo" ControlToValidate="tbEffectiveTo" Display="Dynamic" IsValidEmpty="true" ValidationExpression="^\s{10}|(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(20\d\d)$" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid Date"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceEffectiveTo" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbEffectiveTo" CssClass="EffectiveDateCalendar" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```